# tag synonyms checking

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I've noticed that there are a lot of pending tag synonyms and at best they are barely checked by those able to vote their validity.

This might be because they are more difficult to access directly unlike the close votes and other review queues.

For myself to suggest a tag synonim i have to go on help centre, then press priveleges, then press create tag synonyms then press the link to /tag/synonyms.

Would such a privelege be better more easily accessible? Or should this question just remind people to vote for pending tag synonym?s

Comment: This problem, and several related ones, have been raised [several times over the years over at Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22tag+synonyms%22+%22review%22+is%3Aquestion+%5Bfeature-request%5D). It doesn't look like the feature's been changed since it was first [implemented in 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57983/). FWIW I had no idea this was a thing until I saw this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Speaking for myself, I'm ashamed to admit that I didn't realize that there was a list of suggested synonyms that needed checking. Here's a direct link to it: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest

I just went through and mod-approved most of the outstanding suggestions. I'll try to remember to check back in there from time to time.

If you know of a particular tag synonym proposal that you'd like people to take a look at, feel free to bring it up in [our chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam).

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=26645828#26645828

Comment: @DoubleAA https://youtu.be/q9dbd_dIDy8

Answer (score 5):

It is actually not easy for a synonym to get approved without moderator intervention. In order for a user to vote to approve a synonym, in addition to meeting the reputation threshold the user must have a score of at least 5 in that tag. We only have 139 users who meet the reputation threshold in the first place, many of whom are no longer active on the site. And four approval votes are necessary for a synonym to be approved. Many of the lesser used tags probably don't even have four users who meet both requirements for voting. And even the few users who can approve suggestions probably only visit the synonyms page rarely.

This problem has been discussed at length on the network-wide Meta site, most notably in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127459/does-the-tag-synonym-suggestion-system-work), and several suggestions have been made. However, it does not seem like the system will be drastically improved in the near future. If you want to draw attention to a particular synonym proposal, you can mention it in Chat or in a dedicated Meta post.

(As an aside, you don't need to go to the Help Center to propose a synonym. You can actually propose it from the tag page itself.)